# CakePHP 2, Mysql - how to handle sorting by rating with individual ratings

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Let's say, we have some items "X" in the database, which can be rated. The ratings are saved individually in a separate table. The overall rating is calculated with a pretty complicated formula, which makes it almost impossible to implement it in pure MySQL.

The question I am asking is: how to deal with such an architecture to achieve the following:

- storage of individual ratings
- quick sort by overall rating?

My idea was: each time a rating is added, changed or removed, the value would be cached in a special column in the table with items "X". The problem is, what happens if two persons rate at the same time. There are MySQL transactions - are they the right approach? If so, how to do it right?

Another idea would be to have a cronjob calculating the ratings every x minutes or hours, but when the database gets very big, it would take forever and it could overload the server. Additionally, the sorting visible to the user would not be always accurate.

I am pretty desperate about this problem.

Comment: Very simple: if a user has a rating add a rating column. rating should be a double so that you can do things like 4.5 or 3.2 etc... There's no point storing count and doing math within this, only store the overall rating. After vote is inserted into a votes table, then you calculate right then what new vote is via doing an average on all those values. There won't be a problem with two votes at the same time because select query will wait on insert query to finish. Then simply index the rating column for users so that you can quickly sort it without mysql looking at more rows than it has to.

Comment: This better explains what's going on in the background when you run queries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html

Comment: I am not really sure. When two persons vote at almost the same time, the script would get for both of them the "old" rating, re-calculate the overall rating and write the new value. And then it would be random, which one gets saved as first and which as second. Is it correct?

Comment: So you are absolutely sure it would be safe?

Comment: Absolutely. MySQL uses locking mechanisms and queue-like system to process queries to prevent things exactly like you are describing. If 1,000 users did this at the same exact time, you'd still be okay. I would mostly be concerned about proper indexing. I.e. votes table should have index on the user_id and users table should have index on rating... will make fetching data (i.e. AVG(rating_column)) to get the new rating and sorting users faster. If you are dealing with large amounts of data a lack of proper indexing can severely impact query execution time.

Comment: Ok, it's no that easy as AVG, but I get the point. I didn't know that MySQL is so safe. Thank you a lot. You helped me really :) Have a nice day/evening.

Comment: I meant to get the average to append "cache" column. I.e. if you have votes table with columns user_id, and rating you can easily get new overall rating for a user with ID 2 via doing SELECT AVG(rating) FROM votes_table WHERE user_id=2, then simply update users table to reflect rating equals that average.

Comment: Ok, understand. Thanks a lot for your helpful advices.